# Search DHCP pool and exclusion IP addresses from MS DHCP dump file in text format. Then define new DHCP Pool

Tags: python, dhcp

I've DHCP dump file in text format from MS DHCP server. I need to subtract exclusion IP address from DHCP Pool and create new range without exclusion IP's.

### **DHCP DUMP file format:**

> Dhcp Server \PTLISWSA002.prg-dc.xyz.com Scope 2.10.28.0 Add iprange
>   2.10.28.1 2.10.29.254 BOTH
>
> Dhcp Server \PTLISWSA002.prg-dc.xyz.com Scope 2.10.28.0 add
>   excluderange 
>   2.10.28.1 2.10.28.20
>
> Dhcp Server \PTLISWSA002.prg-dc.xyz.com Scope 2.10.28.0 add
>   excluderange 2.10.28.246 2.10.28.254
>
> Dhcp Server \PTLISWSA002.prg-dc.xyz.com Scope 2.10.28.0 add
>   excluderange 2.10.28.231 2.10.28.233
>
> Dhcp Server \PTLISWSA002.prg-dc.xyz.com Scope 2.10.28.0 add
>   excluderange 2.10.29.1 2.10.29.20
>
> Dhcp Server \PTLISWSA002.prg-dc.xyz.com Scope 2.10.28.0 add
>   excluderange 2.10.29.231 2.10.29.233
>
> Dhcp Server \PTLISWSA002.prg-dc.xyz.com Scope 2.10.28.0 add
>   excluderange 2.10.29.246 2.10.29.254

---

```
import csv
from netaddr import *

    with open(input_file_name, 'r') as f:

        data = []
        count_line = 0

        for line in f:
            if 'iprange' in line:
                count_line +=1  # Counting total number of line with "iprange"
                field = line.split()

                start_ip = field[7]
                end_ip = field[8]

                dhcp_range = list(iter_iprange(start_ip, end_ip))


    with open(input_file_name, 'r') as f:

        for line in f:

            if 'excluderange' in line:
                get_ex_add = line.split()

                start_ex_add = get_ex_add[7]
                end_ex_add = get_ex_add[-1]

                dhcp_exc_range = list(IPSet(IPRange(start_ex_add, end_ex_add)).iter_ipranges())

                final_result = (dhcp_range - dhcp_exc_range)
```

It needs to create new DHCP Pool range after deducting exclusion range of IPs/single IP. E.g.: There are DHCP Pool range 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254, and exclusion range 192.168.1.150 - 192.168.1.160, 192.168.1.200, 192.168.1.250.

**Expected output:** New Pool range - 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.149, 192.168.1.161 - 192.168.1.199, 192.168.1.201 - 192.168.1.249, 192.168.1.251 - 192.168.1.254.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: And what is your problem? Could you edit your post and include a question. How does it go wrong? Is there an error message? What is the expected output?

Comment: It needs to create new DHCP Pool range after deducting exclusion range of IPs/single IP. E.g.: There are DHCP Pool range 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254, and exclusion range 192.168.1.150 - 192.168.1.160, 192.168.1.200, 192.168.1.250.

Comment: Expected output: New Pool range - 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.149, 192.168.1.161 - 192.168.1.199, 192.168.1.201 - 192.168.1.249, 192.168.1.251 - 192.168.1.254.

Comment: If you have important information, add it to the question. Don't bury it down here in the comments. Comments are just meant for side discussions to help you get your question into shape.

Comment: Thanks, PM 2Ring for your advice.